# Add line at the end of text

Tags: cursor-motions, text-generation

I have 5000 text files in a folder with different names.
I just need to add one more line to the end in all files.

Example:

```
HELLO HELLO 
HELLO HELLO
```

I need make it

```
HELLO HELLO 
HELLO HELLO 
abc
```

I just need to add "abc" to the last line.

Comment: Maybe some combination of :arg  combined with an :argdo %s///ge command and :w  ? See help :arg, :argdo. Also, hello.

Comment: Or, you could investigate the methods in this similar question on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804405/search-and-replace-in-vim-across-all-the-project-files).

Comment: I'm not sure I would use vim for this, but rather a batch or shell script.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use the `argument-list` for this.

First you have to add all files to the argument list and then you can use `argdo` to operate on all of them.

So first let's populate the argument list. There's two ways to do this. The first is to go to your directory and open vim with `vim *`. This will open vim with all of the files in the directory open on the argument list. If you can't do that, you can do this (admittedly more complex solution) instead. Open the first file and do this:

```
:for file in split(glob('*'), '\n')
:   exe "argadd ". file
: endfor
```

- `split()`: Splits a string into a list
- `glob()`: Expands wildcards (This is what gets all the file names for us)
- `argadd`: Adds the file to the argument list.

Now that the argument list is populated we can use `argdo` to do an operation on *ALL* of them at once.

```
:argdo execute "normal! Goabc\<Esc>:w\<CR>"
```

- `execute`: Allows us to use the keys `Escape` and `Enter`
- `normal!`: Does the following normal mode commands on the buffer
- `G`: Go to the end of the file
- `o`: Open a new line and go into insert mode
- `abc`: Inserts `abc` into the text. Change this to whatever you need
- `\<Esc>`: Hits the Escape key to get us out of insert mode.
- `:w\<CR>`: Saves the file

See `:h argdo`, `:h execute`, `:h normal`, `:h argadd`, `:h split`, and `:h glob` for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different version. Call Vim from the directory with all files:
`vim *.txt`

Now you can do `:bufdo call append('$', 'abc') | upd`, which will run through your buffer list and add a single line 'abc' at the end and write the file before changing the next file.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not to leave the command-line if I don't have to. The following command run from the terminal should do the trick:

```
echo "abc" | tee -a *.txt
```